# Why does java.util.Optional not have Some and None subclasses?

Tags: java, option-type

In Java 8, the `Optional` class is implemented as a final container class that defines `isPresent` depending on the value being `null`. That means that it is not possible to have an `Optional(null)`, which although not commonly used, seems like a design flaw to me. In particular, this defeats the purpose of having an optional in the first place, because you can simply set a variable to `null` and do the usual `if (x != null)`, without the overhead introduced by `Optional`. Furthermore, the `Optional` class has to check if the `value == null` for every single operation performed on it.

In Scala however, the `Option` trait is much more sophisticated: It has the `Some` subclass for existent values and the `None` subclass for non-existent values. This eliminates the need for `null`-checks inside the class and allows `Some(null)` values.

My question is why the Java designers chose not to follow this subclass principle as well.

Comment: It doesn't have to check it for every operation, as `value` is final. As it happens, the check is there but is unlikely to stay there after JIT compilation. Having said that, I don't really understand what your problem is. If you find yourself calling `Optional.isPresent()` a lot, you're probably doing something wrong. What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to know why they did not choose to go the subclassing path, because that makes a lot more sense. Speculating into the future of Java 10 a bit, the current design is not going to work well with specialization either, because there won't be a way to disambiguate an `Optional<int>.empty` and `Optional(0)`.

Comment: `Optional<int>` isn't valid syntax, so I wouldn't worry about it. There is however `OptionalInt`, which handles all the values correctly, specifically `OptionalInt.of(0).isPresent() == true`

Comment: You don't say. Is Java 10 out yet? I don't think so.

Comment: So basically we are speculating about a version of Java that hasn't even been designed yet? Good luck with that. :)

Comment: No, we are speculating why the Java designers chose to make Optional a single class while already having Java 10 in mind. There is lots of talks about value classes and specialization, both of which are planned for that, from years ago.

Comment: Since it uses a static factory method for instantiation, there's nothing stopping subclassing in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Java has `empty()` and `ofNullable(null)`. Other tool methods exist too. Scala uses subclassing, case classes where other languages (still) use other notions. Scala sees typing a bit more operational.

Java Optional is workable; come with code examples. Using a `Stream` for an Optional might be more in the character of Scala maybe, allowing fluent design with chaining calls in a bit more comfortable way.

It lives with null and is more a recommendation as you stated.

Comment: `ofNullable(null)` gives you `Option.empty`, merely avoiding the NPE that would be thrown by `Optional.of(null)`.